# Scrolling a ScrollViewer to the bottom in WPF when a new line is added to a TextBlock in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer, eventtrigger

I'm trying to keep the vertical scroll bar at the bottom (the latest entry), but at the moment, the scroll bar just stays in the same place, so as content is being added to the string, the scroll bar moves to the top.

I know that I can use the `ServerScroll.ScrollToEnd()` property in my code-behind to move the bar to the end. But is there a way to automatically do this is xaml? (so that I don't have to call this property every time I add to the string).

**XAML**

```xml
<ScrollViewer Name="ServerScroll"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <TextBlock Name="serverConsole"
               Margin="5"
               Background="White"
               TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**Code-behind**

```cs
private void example_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ServerConsole += "asdf\r\n";      // binded to TextBlock
    ServerScroll.ScrollToEnd();    
}
```

Comment: Under what conditions exactly do you want to scroll to the end? Everytime the content of the `ScrollViewer` is changed? Everytime the `Text` of the `TextBlock` changes? I think your solution in code-behind is pretty clear and straightforward btw, I suspect making that in XAML would be tricky and less clear.

Comment: @CorentinPane Everytime a new line is added to the string binded to `TextBlock`, so that the latest entry can be seen at all times. I just thought that adding `.ScrollToEnd()` after every new entry was redundant and was wondering if there was a shorter way, perhaps in a xaml property. I guess not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**With a TextBox, reacting to `TextBox.TextChanged`**

If you want to scroll to the end everytime the `Text` property of your `TextBlock` is changed, I would recommend switching to a `TextBox` so that you can hookup to its `TextChanged` event using `System.Windows.Interactivity`:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:ei="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Width="50" Height="25" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Name="ServerScroll"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <TextBox Name="serverConsole"
                       Margin="5"
                       Background="White"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                        <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="ScrollToEnd" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=ServerScroll}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TextBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**With a TextBlock, reacting to `Button.Click`**

If you wish to scroll to the end whenever your `Button` is clicked, you can use the same technique to hook-up to its `Click` event:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:ei="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Width="50" Height="25" Click="Button_Click">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="ScrollToEnd" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=ServerScroll}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Name="ServerScroll"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <TextBlock Name="serverConsole"
                       Margin="5"
                       Background="White"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap">
            </TextBlock>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**With a ListView, reacting to `CollectionChanged`**

It looks like you really want to use an `ItemsControl` instead of a `TextBlock` though, because you're talking about entries and everything. You could switch to a `ListView` and hook-up to its `CollectionChanged` event as well:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:ei="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Width="50" Height="25" Click="Button_Click"/>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Name="ServerScroll"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger SourceObject="{Binding MyList}" EventName="CollectionChanged">
                        <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="ScrollToEnd" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=ServerScroll}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </ListView>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And in your view model:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<string> MyList { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear examples! I think this would do